# Reverse the words in a sentence using two while loops

Tags: c

I cant get the right output and I wonder where my mistake is. Probably there are mistakes in loops in the counting reverse. The main problem in my whole code is that it only outputs marks but not words. Also the program must end automatically when putting these three punctuation and shows the output.

This is the expected behavior:

Input: `my name is jake.`//terminates when putting `.` and automatically shows the output

Output: `jake is name my.`

Here is the program fragment of my first loop:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 70

int main(void) {

    char array[N] = { 0 };

    char *p;
    char mark = 0;
    int c;
    p = array;

    scanf("%d", &c);

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (p < array + N) {
            if (c == '.' || c == '!' || c == '?')
                mark = c;
            if (c == ' ') {
                *p = '\0';
                *p++;
            } else
                *p = c;
        }
    }
    *p = '\0';
    while (--p > array) {
        if (p[1])
            printf("%s", p + 1);
    }
    printf("%s", array);
    if (mark)
        printf("%c", mark);
}
```

Comment: Please post the output you are getting. Also, you might want to take a look at `strtok`.

Comment: This code has no input, output, and never even saves off `c` except for three specific equivalences. Further, as shown, it cannot compile to a runnable program. Provide a proper [mcve] that demonstrates your problem,

Comment: indenting your code properly will make it easier to read.

Comment: I will fix it.Thank you for warning.

Comment: share the whole program you've written.

Comment: @SparKot I will edit right now

Comment: `Also the program must end when putting these three punctuation and show the output.` Give an example for that.

Comment: Is it more clear?Because I dont know how can I explain in other way.

Comment: You want to stop reading when a punctuation is encountered in input. Say when you input `My name is John. McKintosh.` Output should be just `John is name My.`. Just add a break in while-loop that reads input.

Comment: I know ı ask too much but could you organize your code according to that? According to my output in here,my book,they only use a sentence. I think that is why they want us to stop program when ıt encounters a punctuation. I will write what ı have done in my question code.

Comment: Okay now I saw the changes.Thank you so much for helping.I gave so much trouble to you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code with little modifications:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 70

int main (void) {

    char array[N+1] = { 0 };

    char* p;
    char mark = 0;
    int c;
    p = array;

    //scanf ("%d", &c); //serves no purpose : are you reading sentence length here?

    while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (p < array + N) {
            if (c == '.' || c == '!' || c == '?') {
                mark = c;
                *p++ = '\0';
                break;          // stop reading input
            } else if (c == ' ') {
                *p++ = '\0';
            } else
                *p++ = c;
        }
    }
    *p = '\0';
    while (--p > array) {
        if ('\0' == *p && '\0' != *(p + 1))
            printf ("%s ", p + 1);
    }
    printf ("%s", array);
    if (mark)
        printf ("%c", mark);

    return 0;
}
```

There is a better way, but that will make use of string library functions.

Comment: I totally forgot scanf is useless.Thank you so much for editing my question and also helping.

Comment: can you help me about when putting ! or ? or . program termiantes.How can I do that?Also there is a problem with input three or more words. my name is jake.-->.jakeisname my.

Comment: I don't understand, rephrase the question. Put `!, ? .` where? Terminate when?

Comment: Oh okay now I see my mistake but point still remains beginning of the sentence and also end of the sentence.

Comment: terminating when putting . or ! or ? and I will edit question immediately.

Comment: You have undefined behavior if the input string is longer than `N` because the last string may not be null terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative where the original string is not modified:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_swap(const char *s) {
    int p1, p2, tail = strcspn(s, ".!?\n");
    for (p1 = p2 = tail; p1 > 0; p1--) {
        if (s[p1 - 1] == ' ') {
            printf("%.*s ", p2 - p1, s + p1);
            p2 = p1 - 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%.*s%s", p2, s, s + tail);
}

int main() {
    char array[80];
    if (fgets(array, sizeof array, stdin))
        print_swap(array);
    return 0;
}
```